# What is the practical way to add a new replica to the existing cluster?

Tags: clickhouse

I have done some experiments as under and wonder if there is a better way and/or etc.

1. started a cluster with 2 nodes with:

   - <remote_servers>: logs_cluster with 2 shards 1 replica; <macros> for shard and replica
   - a table with ReplicateMergeTree
2. inserted some data into 2 nodes, separately and verified them
3. added 2 new nodes into the cluster and for the new nodes:

   - <remote_servers>: logs_cluster with 2 shards 2 replicas; <macros> for shard and replica
   - a table with ReplicateMergeTree
   - once the tables are created, CH copies the data from the existing (shard) nodes to new ones
4. insert data into any of 4 nodes: replication works

Is this a practical way to add replica node(s)?
The old nodes are still with the "2 shards 1 replica" configurations. Should I update them so all 4 nodes have the same cluster configurations?
Is there an option not to copy the existing data at step #3? E.g., if there are huge data in the existing nodes, I may like to keep them as they are and make replication works for the new data only.

CH version: 23.1.3 using ClickHouse Keeper.

Comment: Did you figure out the best way to add new nodes?

Comment: Sorry, no, I have not spent more effort on this. @AyushChauhan